# How to configure Multisite Network with randomized hostnames?

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting, redirect, mod-rewrite, apache

I'm trying to convert a freshly-installed and functional WordPress into a multisite network. But I'm having problems because of our Apache configuration.

We use Apache to randomly redirect requests for domain.com to one of two application servers: app1.domain.com or app2.domain.com. The problem is that WordPress redirects to DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE (defined in wp-config.php) if the current browser domain differs from that. This results in a 310 redirect loop. Here's an example of what happens:

1. User requests domain.com/apps/wordpress/
2. Apache redirects to app1.domain.com/apps/wordpress/
3. Because redirect domain does not match DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE, WordPress redirects to DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE (domain.com/apps/wordpress/)
4. Return to step 1 and repeat

What I'd like to do is set all WordPress links and URLs to **domain.com** and have WordPress ignore the fact that **app1.domain.com** or **app2.domain.com** is *actually* being retrieved. Is this possible?

Here are the relevant Apache conf files (simplified), in case I'm not being quite clear:

**application_servers.conf:**

```
domain.com-prod-http  app1.domain.com:80|app2.domain.com:80
```

**httpd.conf:**

```
RewriteMap server rnd:conf/application_servers.conf
RewriteRule ^/apps/*([^/]*)/*(.*) http://${server:domain.com-prod-http}/apps/$1/$2 [P,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After banging my head on this for a few days, I found a solution that works.

Just add the following to wp-config.php:

```
if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] ) ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
}
```

This will force WordPress to use the requested domain, instead of the proxy domain.